# PCRE format to QRegexp format

Tags: regex, qt

I have a PCRE format regular expression:
  **`<a\s*href=\"([^<]*)\"([^<]*)\((.*?)\)\">`**

but i can not use it in QT, how can i 
convert it to QRegexp format to make it work in QT.

Thanks

Comment: Did you know that links can be written with with capitalized tags and attributes?  Or that attribute values aren't always enclosed in double quotes?  Or that sometimes there might be a space between the "<" and the "a", or between the "href" and the "="? or the closing quote and the ">"?  Using regexen to scrape HTML is almost guaranteed to omit some results that you thought you wanted, but couldn't represent in your RE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [reading the documentation](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qregexp.html)?  Specifically the section called "Notes for Perl Users"?  It appears that this should be pretty straightforward:

```
QRegExp regex( "<a\\s*href=\\"([^<]*)\\"([^<]*)\\((.*?)\\)\\">", 
    Qt::CaseSensitive, QRegExp:: RegExp2 );
```

Note that all I did there was double-up the backslashes, since C will "eat" one when interpreting the code.  However, I have my doubts that you wanted the quotes double-backslashed, so perhaps this is more like what you wanted:

```
QRegExp regex( "<a\\s*href=\"([^<]*)\"([^<]*)\\((.*?)\\)\">", 
    Qt::CaseSensitive, QRegExp:: RegExp2 );
```

I also don't know why you are trying to match 3 quote marks in the expression, but that is beyond the scope of what you asked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am not good at regular expression, i want to match some google results, but i tested my regex(<a\s*href=\"([^<]*)\"([^<]*)\((.*?)\)\">), it can match something, but when i use it in QT by using QRegExp and also use double-backslashed, i can not work. Maybe my regular expression is wrong.